# setting up an EC2 server with rvm via scripting

Tags: ruby, rvm, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm looking for a way to install rvm, install a specific ruby version (using rvm) and set this installed ruby version as default. Before I can install rvm I have to install gcc and some other very basic software packages. What I've tried so far:

1) Using net/ssh

- I have to simulate a pseudo tty to be able to sudo some commands and up to now,
  I could not figure out, how to tell a success full command completion from a not success full one.
- after installing rvm, I've stumbled over problems using rvm ("rvm is not a function", error messages, leading to not being able to set a default ruby version).

2) Using capistrano

- In the ssh output are newlines inserted so that a progress bar for example is been printed in a new line every time, some progress is made. That's something I can live with.
- Same Problems with rmv, I'm able to install rvm, but I'm unable to set a default: `rvm --default use 1.9.2` for example. No error message, but when I've log in later, no default is set and `ruby -v`shows the old system ruby.

3) Using capistrano and rvm-capistrano

- Now I ran into the problem, that very task that I try to execute prior to installing rvm fails, because there seems to be some magic that fiddles with the shell default:

> ```
>  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' yum install --assumeyes git gcc-c++ autoconf automake make patch zlib-devel libtool bzip2-devel"
>    servers: ["ec2-54-247-142-214.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"]
>    [ec2-54-247-142-214.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] executing command
> ** [out :: ec2-54-247-142-214.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com] bash: /home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell: No such file or directory
>     command finished in 2094ms
> failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell 'default' -c 'sudo -p '\\''sudo password: '\\'' yum install --assumeyes git gcc-c++ autoconf automake make patch zlib-devel libtool bzip2-devel'" on ec2-54-247-142-214.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
> rake aborted!
> ```

Here the commands I issue to install rvm/ruby:

```
run 'curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable'
run 'rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320'
run 'echo "[[ -s \"\$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\" ]] && source \"\$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm\"" >> .bashrc'
run 'rvm --default use ruby-1.9.2-p320'
run 'which ruby && ruby -v'
```

and here the error messages that is issued as response to `rvm --default use 1.9.2`

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
You need to change your terminal settings to allow shell login.
Please visit https://rvm.io/workflow/screen/ for example.
```

4.1) Using capistrano and rvm-capistrano and hacking a little bit

Update: With the help from mpapis at the RVM chat, I was able to come up with this working solution now:
    require "rvm/capistrano"

```
role :server, ENV[ 'base_image_setup_server' ] if ENV[ 'base_image_setup_server' ]

default_run_options[:pty] = true
default_run_options[:shell] = :bash

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.2-p320'
set :rvm_type, :user

def rvm_bin
    '$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm'
end

namespace :images do

    task :install_basics do
        run "#{sudo} yum install --assumeyes git gcc-c++ autoconf automake make patch zlib-devel libtool bzip2-devel"
        run "#{sudo} yum update --assumeyes"
    end

    task :install_ruby do
        rvm.install_rvm
        rvm.install_ruby
        run "#{rvm_bin} alias create default #{rvm_ruby_string}"
        run 'echo "source ~/.rvm/environments/default" >> $HOME/.bashrc'
        run 'which ruby && ruby -v'
    end

    ... 

    desc 'build the base-image'
    task :base_image do 
        install_basics
        install_ruby
        install_boost
        install_rake_and_rack
        install_sioux
        test_sioux
    end
```

The main different is, that RVM is *not* used as a function, but the program direct.

kind regards,
Torsten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check RVM site for Capistrano integration https://rvm.io/integration/capistrano

There are tasks to install RVM and Ruby:

```
after 'deploy:setup', 'ubuntu:install'
after 'deploy:setup', 'rvm:install_rvm' # do it only with deploy setup
before 'deploy', 'rvm:install_ruby'     # do it on every deploy
namespace :ubuntu do
  desc "setup ubuntu system"
  task :install do
    run "apt-get install -y make ...", :shell => "sh"
    ...
  end
end
```

And you run the standard:

```
cap deploy:setup
cap deploy:cold
```

Also you might want to have a look on my example rails app for simple and working deployment script: https://github.com/mpapis/ad and my blog post about it: http://niczsoft.com/2012/03/fast-deployment-using-capistrano-rvm-and-more/

Comment: @mapsis But don't have a task named 'deploy' but I have a task to do _before_  installing rvm/ruby (installing a compiler for example). Thank you.

Comment: updated, also note with RVM2 this pre step will be not needed as all required components will be installed with ruby ... also you should be able to setup external dependencies

Comment: I don't think that your example will work, because require "rvm/capistrano" will change the terminal to "/home/ec2-user/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell". I've fixed this by explicitly re-changing the shell to bash. I will update the question with was works for me so far. But thank you for you efforts.