# installing ruby on EC2 Amazon Unix, using capistrano

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rvm, capistrano

I'm trying to install ruby 1.9.3-p545 using capistrano [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940571/setting-up-an-ec2-server-with-rvm-via-scripting). What worked for me a year ago, seems to be broken by rvm:

```
require "rvm/capistrano"

set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-1.9.3-p327'
set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_install_ruby_params, '--with-opensll-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr'

def rvm_bin
    '$HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm'
end

namespace :deploy do
    task :step do
        rvm.install_rvm
        run "#{rvm_bin} autolibs enable"
        rvm.install_ruby
        run "#{rvm_bin} alias create default #{rvm_ruby_string}"
        run 'echo "source ~/.rvm/environments/default" >> $HOME/.bashrc'
        run 'which ruby && ruby -v'
        run 'gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc rake rack net-ssh bundler'
    end
end
```

It looks like the `rvm autolibs enable` doesn't work anymore, because I get the following error message:

```
Checking requirements for amazon.
Missing required packages: libyaml-devel libffi-devel readline-devel openssl-devel bison
RVM autolibs is now configured with mode '2' => 'check and stop if missing',
please run `rvm autolibs enable` to let RVM do its job or run and read `rvm autolibs [help]`
```

I think there must be others out there, using capistrano to install ruby. I've tried to install ruby from sources, but then I ran into problems with missing yaml support.

Any thoughts, any pointers?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is now called: `rvm requirements`

Comment: @IanRodriguez Thank Ian, I will give it a try tomorrow.

Comment: if you want to install ruby from source, install `libyaml` first

Comment: check with the missing libraries that is says as missing

Comment: @GhostRider Adding the missing libraries was the point with the `rvm autolibs enable` part.

Comment: I'm currently going to install ruby without using rvm. As the installations only purpose is to setup a web server, I think installing the ruby at /usr/local/bin is not the best option. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Rvm should never be an issue, i would recommend using it as in future if you want use a different version of ruby it will be a hassle

Comment: For me, it was almost ever an issue with rvm. I really appreciate the work they do, but when it comes to installing with capistrano, it seems to be always big trouble to me.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940571/setting-up-an-ec2-server-with-rvm-via-scripting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is my solution without rmv. Please let me know, if you have any improvements, thoughts or critics:

```
namespace :deploy do
    RUBY_VERSION = 'ruby-1.9.3-p545'

    task :step do
        # remove default ruby and install dependencies     
        run "#{sudo} yum erase --assumeyes ruby"
        run "#{sudo} yum install --assumeyes readline-devel openssl-devel libyaml-devel"
        # Add the installed ruby to PATH
        run "echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin' >> $HOME/.bashrc"
        run "source $HOME/.bashrc"
        # Build and install
        run "wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/1.9/#{RUBY_VERSION}.tar.gz"
        run "tar zxvf #{RUBY_VERSION}.tar.gz"
        run "cd #{RUBY_VERSION} && ./configure --disable-install-doc --enable-shared --prefix=$HOME && make && make install"
        # Check installation and install very basic gems
        run 'which ruby && ruby -v'
        run "gem install --no-ri --no-rdoc rake rack net-ssh bundler"
    end
end
```